# Does spidev support QSPI?

Tags: drivers

Our project is runs on a SAMA7G54 running a BuildRoot version of Linux. Our ultimate goal is to use Python's spidev wrappers to communicate with custom hardware (NOT a memory chip) via QSPI.

I'm new to Linux drivers, etc, but looking over the spidev documentation, I see no mention of QSPI -- it all appears to be geared to "ordinary" SPI communication with MOSI, MISO, SCLK and CS.

So: can the spidev driver be configured to communicate using QSPI, and if so, how?  If not, what are my options for driving a QSPI hardware interface from userland?